# score in listview from sharedpreferences

Tags: android, arrays, listview, preferences, shared

I want to create a list with scores for my quiz app. When you finish the quiz, you get a score and I save it with Shared Preferences(and also the name of the player).Then, in ScoreActivity, I'm getting the username and the score and I want them added to the list. But I don't know why the list has just the last score in it.

Here is my ScoreActivity.class, maybe you can help me:

```
public class ScoreActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listView;
     List<String> scoreList = new ArrayList<String>();





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);



        listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_score);




        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String name = sharedPref.getString("name","");

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("userScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String score = sharedPreferences.getString("score","");


        scoreList.add(name+"    "+score);







            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this,
                    R.layout.my_list, scoreList );

            listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }


    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show me the code, how you save the score and username ?

Comment: SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("userScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
            editor.putString("score", String.valueOf(score));
            editor.apply();

SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("name",editName.getText().toString());
        editor.apply();

Comment: YOu are only saving one score and username. So, you get only one score and username.

Comment: I'm getting the username from the register activity and the score from result activity. How can I save all the scores?

Comment: Okay, I will write the code in my answer. Give me a min

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, create a custom Class like this ;

```
public class UserInfoClass implements Serializable{

    String userName;
    String score;

    public String getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(String score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }


    }


}
```

Now create an array list like this:

```
List<UserInfoClass> users= new ArrayList<>();
```

Now whenever you want to save a user's score and name, do the following:

```
UserInfoClass userobject = new UserInfoClass();        
userobject.setScore("50");
userobject.setUserName("Username");
users.add(userobject);
```

Now you have to save this list. Then whenever you have to add another user, first retrieve the already saved list from SharedPreferences and then add that user's info and then save it again. Finally, [this](http://blog.nkdroidsolutions.com/arraylist-in-sharedpreferences/) link will tell you how to save an ArrayList in SharedPreferences:

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't know how to do the last part. I don't understand how to save the ArrayList in shared preferences, I tried with Gson but it says that it cannot be solved...I don't know, maybe because of the API level, I'm using 10.

Comment: Can't you change your api level ?

Comment: I'm afraid to do so. I thought it was easier to create that scoreboard, but I was wrong. Anyway, thanks again for trying to help me!! :D